# How to know if an option element has a value attribute set?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting a `null` when a 'comment' value is selected.

Let us have the following example:

```
<select id="assignToGroup" name="assign_to_group">
    <option>Select a Group</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

When I do the `$('#assignToGroup').val()` while the 'Select a Group' option is selected, I'm actually getting 'Select a Group' instead a `null`.

Same happens trying to do some other functions like `attr` and so on.

Any pointers in what function would return `null` or maybe `""` for when the first option is selected which doesn't have any value attribute set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just add `value=""` on the "Select a Group" option, but alternatively you could do

```js
$('#assignToGroup').on('change',function() {
  console.log($('#assignToGroup option:selected').attr('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="assignToGroup" name="assign_to_group">
    <option>Select a Group</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

This will give `undefined` for the "Select a Group" option.

Comment: @mimoralea Works for me. Check [this codepen](http://codepen.io/mnpenner/pen/RNpYKe)

Comment: @Mark this is weird, it does work in the fiddle, locally though I still get the other 'Select a Group' value. I do have jQuery for sure, since I'm doing a bunch other request. Any ideas on what might be my issue? I tried in both Firefox and Chrome and both do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behaviour, if the option has no value, it will show the text value as default:

You can do this:

```
<option value="null">Select a Group</option>
```

or:

```
<option value="-1">Select a Group</option>
```

Comment: n.b. this will return string `"null"` not JS `null`

Comment: I know, is just key that you can internally use later in your to identify if the option has a value.

Comment: For a moment I thought it was good, but it is not the JS `null`... Thanks though.